# Document oriented database - How to abstract relationship

Tags: nosql, couchdb, relation, abstraction

I'm using CouchDB (similar to MongoDB) as main Database and NodeJS in the back-end.

Since CouchDB is schemaless, I have to handle the relationship between entities in business rules. Currently I manage this relation directly in controllers - Here is a really simple example of how I implement this relationship:

```
async function createProject(user, project) {
    project.userId = user.id;
    let response = await projectsDB.save(project);
    return response;
}
```

Is there an architecture pattern to manage such relations. I'm thinking about abstract the relation layer in the domain entities or in the database module directly - The controller just don't seems to be the place where I should manage it.

I could do the following by managing such relations when on entities instanciations

```
async function createProject(user, project) {
    let project = new Project(project, user); // if no user provided --> throw
    let response = await projectDB.save(project);
    return response;
}
```

Or it could be in the DB layer:

```
 async function createProject(user, project) {
        let projectDB = new DB(user); // if no user provided --> throw
        let response = await projectDB.save(project);
        return response;
    }
```

Comment: It should be in the domain layer. Your controller will be cleaner and you'll have a higher cohesion if your model validations are in the model layer. 

Most of the ORM define those validations in the model layer as well.